# Optimism Swap problem in Web3.py

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python, swaps, optimism

Error in code when trying to swap from Optimism to usdt or usdc via Web3.py library

I have code that swap successfully to Arbitrum, Polygon but error in Optimism.
I am using MetaAggregationRouterV2 and function: swap (link: https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x6131b5fae19ea4f9d964eac0408e4408b66337b5#code).

and I get an error for example:
Error! TX: [0xf1a6b7deef83d993baa826d75de192980a915ab92bd22882b552ba6d2f58b5a1](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/tx/0xf1a6b7deef83d993baa826d75de192980a915ab92bd22882b552ba6d2f58b5a1)

Code:

```
import time
from web3 import Web3

class swapExampleP():
    def __init__(self, wallet: str, private_key: str, web3RpcUrl: str, 
        swap_amount: int, to_token: str):
        
        #Setup Wallet Informations and RPC
        #Usually we place these info in separate .env or .py or .json file.
        self.wallet = Web3.to_checksum_address(wallet) #your wallet address
        self.pk = private_key #your wallet private key
        self.rpc = web3RpcUrl #your node or use public rpc
        self.web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.rpc)) #connect to web3

        #Setup Swap Value / Gas limit / Gwei
        #Change these values if you want.
        self.buy_amount = swap_amount #Ether value to spend
        self.gas = 50000 #gas limit
        self.gwei = 0.1  #gwei

        #Setup WETH token address (to spend) and Token address (to buy)
        self.WETH = self.web3.to_checksum_address('0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000042')
        self.token_to_buy = self.web3.to_checksum_address(to_token)

        #Setup router address ( Router Address)
        self.router = self.web3.to_checksum_address('0x6131B5fae19EA4f9D964eAc0408E4408b66337b5')

        #Setup  ABI
        #You can get this ABI directly from Verified Contract Source Code at Etherscan
        self.abi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"clientData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ClientData","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"string","name":"reason","type":"string"}],"name":"Error","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"output","type":"address"}],"name":"Exchange","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalFee","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address[]","name":"recipients","type":"address[]"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"isBps","type":"bool"}],"name":"Fee","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"srcToken","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"dstToken","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"dstReceiver","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"spentAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"returnAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Swapped","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"isWhitelist","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rescueFunds","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"callTarget","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"approveTarget","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"targetData","type":"bytes"},{"components":[{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"srcToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"dstToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"srcReceivers","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"srcAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"feeReceivers","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"feeAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dstReceiver","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"minReturnAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"flags","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"permit","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct MetaAggregationRouterV2.SwapDescriptionV2","name":"desc","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"clientData","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct MetaAggregationRouterV2.SwapExecutionParams","name":"execution","type":"tuple"}],"name":"swap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"returnAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"gasUsed","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"callTarget","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"approveTarget","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"targetData","type":"bytes"},{"components":[{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"srcToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"dstToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"srcReceivers","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"srcAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"feeReceivers","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"feeAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dstReceiver","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"minReturnAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"flags","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"permit","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct MetaAggregationRouterV2.SwapDescriptionV2","name":"desc","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"clientData","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct MetaAggregationRouterV2.SwapExecutionParams","name":"execution","type":"tuple"}],"name":"swapGeneric","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"returnAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"gasUsed","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract IAggregationExecutor","name":"caller","type":"address"},{"components":[{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"srcToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"dstToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"srcReceivers","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"srcAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"feeReceivers","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"feeAmounts","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dstReceiver","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"minReturnAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"flags","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"permit","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct MetaAggregationRouterV2.SwapDescriptionV2","name":"desc","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"executorData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"clientData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"swapSimpleMode","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"returnAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"gasUsed","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"addr","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"bool[]","name":"value","type":"bool[]"}],"name":"updateWhitelist","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'

        #Creating instance.
        #We can call contract functions with this.
        self.router_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=self.router, abi=self.abi)

        # #Do swap.
        self.swap()

    #From here we are going to create Swap function.
    def swap(self):
        # Building transaction with swap parameters
        swap_execution_params = {
                'callTarget': self.router, 
                'approveTarget': self.router, 
                'targetData': b'', 
                'desc': {
                    'srcToken': self.WETH, 
                    'dstToken': self.token_to_buy, 
                    'srcReceivers': [self.wallet],
                    'srcAmounts': [self.web3.to_wei(self.buy_amount, 'ether')], 
                    'feeReceivers': [], 
                    'feeAmounts': [], 
                    'dstReceiver': self.wallet, 
                    'amount': self.web3.to_wei(self.buy_amount, 'ether'), 
                    'minReturnAmount': 0, 
                    'flags': 0, 
                    'permit': b'' 
                },
                'clientData': b'' 
            }
        swap_txn = self.router_contract.functions.swap(swap_execution_params).build_transaction({
                'from': self.wallet,
                'value': self.web3.to_wei(self.buy_amount, 'ether'), 
                'gas': self.gas,
                'gasPrice': self.web3.to_wei(self.gwei, 'gwei'),
                'nonce': self.web3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.wallet),
            })

        # Sign swap transaction and send to blockchain
        signed_txn = self.web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_txn, private_key=self.pk)
        buy_tx = self.web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
        # print("Transaction sent, awaiting for response.")

        # Await for result
        tx_receipt = self.web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(buy_tx)

        # Transaction status verification
        if tx_receipt['status'] == 1:
            print("Success! TX:", self.web3.to_hex(buy_tx))
            return True 
        else:
            print("Error! TX:", self.web3.to_hex(buy_tx))
            return False

swapExampleP(wallet='wallet_adress', private_key='private_key',
swap_amount=0.00001, to_token='0x94b008aA00579c1307B0EF2c499aD98a8ce58e58',
web3RpcUrl='https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/HERE_API')
```